# Ajuda com MVC Pegar valor de checkbox e enviar para o controller variavel bool

Tags: javascript, c#, html, mvc, booleano

Estou tentando enviar o valor dos `checkbox`com `id`, caso o `checkbox` seja `true`, irá criar a coluna.

**VIEW**

```html
<div class="checkbox dadospessoais">
                                            <label>
                                                <input class="dadospessoais" type="checkbox" name="ckNome" id="ckNome" /> Nome
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input class="dadospessoais" type="checkbox" name="ckNomeSocial" id="ckNomeSocial" /> Nome Social
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
```

**MODEL**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;



namespace QJW.Web.Models.RHViewModel
{

 public class FiltroRelatorioCheckbox
    {


        public bool ckNome { get; set; }

        public bool ckNomeSocial { get; set; }

 }
```

**CONTROLLER**

TRECHO DE ONDE QUERO TRABALHAR COM OS RESULTADO DOS `CHECKBOX`.

```
public ActionResult Imprimir( QJW.Web.Models.RHViewModel.FiltroRelatorioCheckbox ckModel)

 {


             if (ckModel.ckNome)
            {
                new DataColumn("Nome", typeof(string)) { AllowDBNull = true };     
            }


}
```

Coloquei um `breakpoint` no `if`, e o `ckNome` vem sempre `false`.

Comment: Você usa rotas ou controller/action?

Comment: uso mas para outras tela, nessa que estou tentando pegar o valor do checkbox só uso essa actionResult ai que coloquei

Answer (score 1):

Pessoal caso alguém esteja com a mesma dúvida, resolvi dessa forma:

```
<div class="checkbox dadospessoais">
    <label>
        <input class="dadospessoais" type="checkbox" name="ckNome" id="ckNome" value="true" /> Nome
        <input name="ckNome" id="ckNome" value="false" type="hidden" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Adicionando um `value="true"` no `input` e `value="false"` no outro sendo `hidden` ele enviará `false` ou `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Como você esta enviando este formulário para a controller?

Você tem que atribuir o valor **true** para o checkbox antes de envia-lo para a controller.

Pode usar uma função js. Exemplo:

```
$(document).on("click", "[type='checkbox']", function(e) {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).attr("value", "true");
        } else {
            $(this).attr("value","false");}
    });
```